# Pop Up Login Form In magento 2

Tags: magento2, loginpopup

Hi am trying to show pop login form in my custom theme

**Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/Layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="custom_customer_form_login" template="Magento_Theme::form/login.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

*****Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/form/login.phtml****

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login $block */
?>
<div class="block block-customer-login" id="popup-modal" style="display:none">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong id="block-customer-login-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Registered Customers')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
        <form class="form form-login"
              action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"
              method="post"
              id="login-form"
              data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <fieldset class="fieldset login" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
                <div class="field note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('If you have an account, sign in with your email address.')) ?></div>
                <div class="field email required">
                    <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="login[username]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getUsername()) ?>" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> id="email" type="email" class="input-text" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field password required">
                    <label for="pass" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="login[password]" type="password" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> class="input-text" id="pass" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
                <div class="actions-toolbar">
                    <div class="primary"><button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign In')) ?></span></button></div>
                    <div class="secondary"><a class="action remind" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getForgotPasswordUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Forgot Your Password?')) ?></span></a></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Vendor/Theme/web/js/custom.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($, modal) {
    'use strict';
 
    return {
        modalWindow: null,
 
        /**
         * Create popUp window for provided element
         *
         * @param {HTMLElement} element
         */
        createPopUp: function (element) {
            var options = {
                'type': 'popup',
                'modalClass': 'popup-authentication',
                'focus': '[name=username]',
                'responsive': true,
                'innerScroll': true,
                'trigger': '.proceed-to-checkout, .some-other-class',
                'buttons': []
            };
 
            this.modalWindow = element;
            modal(options, $(this.modalWindow));
        },
 
        /** Show login popup window */
        showModal: function () {
            $(this.modalWindow).modal('openModal');
        }
    };
});
```

but its not working anyone suggest what is the problem and why it is not working thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @Chikku check this link --- https://popatkaran.wordpress.com/2016/08/17/magento-2-open-login-form-in-popup/

Comment: @MohitPatel i have already tried that too  but it seems like its not working

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this code**

**Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/form/login.phtml**

```
  <div id="your_popup_container" style="display:none">

    <div class="block block-customer-login" id="popup-modal" >
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong id="block-customer-login-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Registered Customers')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content" aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
        <form class="form form-login"
              action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"
              method="post"
              id="login-form"
              data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <fieldset class="fieldset login" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
                <div class="field note"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('If you have an account, sign in with your email address.')) ?></div>
                <div class="field email required">
                    <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="login[username]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getUsername()) ?>" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> id="email" type="email" class="input-text" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field password required">
                    <label for="pass" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="login[password]" type="password" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> class="input-text" id="pass" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
                <div class="actions-toolbar">
                    <div class="primary"><button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign In')) ?></span></button></div>
                    <div class="secondary"><a class="action remind" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getForgotPasswordUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Forgot Your Password?')) ?></span></a></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                'type': 'popup',
                'title': 'your popup title',
                'modalClass': 'your_popup_custom_class',
                'responsive': true,
                'innerScroll': true,
                'buttons': [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Back'),
                    class: 'back_button_class',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                        // any javascript coode
                    }
                }]
            };

            $(document).ready(function(){
                var popup = modal(options, $('#your_popup_container')); 
                $("#your_popup_container").modal("openModal");
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

***Note :-
In above code there is no need to external java script because i have added in phtml file.***

Comment: please check and update me

Comment: hmm i have got that let me check

Comment: na its not working moreover that it creates sign in link in the footer which i generally do not need

Comment: Is popup show or not?

Comment: na its not working and still trying to debug that

Comment: what is problems in now ?

Comment: thats okay am looking in to it will fix it thank you

Comment: if above answer is work for you than vote up and accept because it is help to other people.